# git falsely marks entire file as merge conflict on same platform

Tags: git, macos, git-merge-conflict

**Edit 2**: Looks like the file actually was corrupt. Creating a new one solved this problem, so I guess it was not really git related.

**Edit**: editing some and using `git diff | cat -t` gives something like:

```
diff —git a/css/style.css b/css/style.css
index bd9b50a..8f8f7dc 100644
—- a/css/style.css
+++ b/css/style.css
@@ -1 +1 @@
-/* typo */^M^Mbody {^M  font-size: 16px;^M  line-height: 1.5;^M}^M^Ma {^M  color: #000;^M  color: #0770b2;^M}^M^M.main-carousel .item .carousel-caption .caption-content h1,^Mh1 {^M
```

---

Edit: this does not happen in other files of the repo

We're two guys on OS X working with git. It's just a freaking css file that is constantly being marked as merge conflict for no obvious reason.

Basically, when we both work on the file and for instance we both just change 2 existing, different lines each and commit, one pushes and the other one pulls, that person gets a merge conflict for the entire file.

We've both tried autocrlf to be auto, input and false, but no difference.

Strangely, when I pull and see the conflict message and do a diff, this is being output:

```
diff --cc css/style.css
index 10a8242,6b94ef0..0000000
--- a/css/style.css
+++ b/css/style.css
@@@ -1,1 -1,1 +1,5 @@@
} padding: 15px 0; {x;{b2;0b2;-caption .caption-content h2 {st-child {4d000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
} padding: 15px 0; {x;{b2;0b2;-caption .caption-content h2 {st-child {4d000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 );
++<<<<<<< HEAD
} padding: 15px 0; {x;{b2;0b2;-caption .caption-content h2 {st-child {4d000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
++=======
} padding: 15px 0; {x;{b2;0b2;-caption .caption-content h2 {st-child {4d000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=1 );
++>>>>>>> 7049454e778aa6c9c85d638f7b3898e55dac38d7
```

Which absolutely makes no sense because these lines werent even affected, they dont even appear like that in the css file (what the hell is `} padding: 15px 0; {x;{b2;0b2;-caption .caption-content h2 {st-child` ? ).

This is **both** our global git config (removed user and colors and stuff):

```
[apply]
    whitespace = fix
[core]
    excludesfile = ~/.gitignore
    whitespace = space-before-tab,-indent-with-non-tab,trailing-space
  trustctime = false
  precomposeunicode = false
    fileMode = false
    autocrlf = false
[diff]
    renames = copies
[diff "bin"]
    textconv = hexdump -v -C
[merge]
    log = true
```

I'm really desperate. It looks like something major is wrong. We're using 2.8.1.

Comment: Perhaps one of your editors is adding non-printable characters to the file and those are causing the difference? Try `git diff | cat -t` to see such characters.

Comment: It seems one of you is using an editor which creates incompatible line endings.

Comment: It always makes sense to run `git config merge.conflictstyle diff3` to show the full picture

Comment: Maybe one of your editors is swapping spaces-tabs on the file, or something like that, and when both try to commit together, the conflict is huge... The first thing I would do would be checking that...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado wouldnt that be visible in the diff?

Comment: the "b2;0b2;" could be escape sequences

Comment: @Alex it should. But I've seen in the past some bugs when there are conflicts in that nature (white spaces/unseen chars swapped), Anyway, I can't be sure that is your case (there are other comments here, that seems to be more relevant than mine), but as I said, this would be the first thing I would check.

Comment: @avivr please see the update. it looks the same for both of us when editing a file. is there something specific to look out for? that `@@ -1 +1 @@` drives me crazy

Comment: we're both working with sublime text 3. as i said, for other files in that project this does not occur

Comment: searching for invalid characters in that file using the following regex:

`[^a-zA-Z\-_\.\#\/\{\}\s0-9;\(\):\*,\"%\[\]\=]`

finds nothing, so i guess there are no invalid characters

Comment: @Alex the `@@ -1 +1 @@` are just part of the [diff format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format). The `^M` chars you are seeing are carriage returns (CR). Try the `cat -t` on the diff output of the merge conflict. It's possible you have different configurations for Sublime text (possible even only for css files), causing the problem.

Comment: it turns out that file somehow was corrupt. In the chrome dev tools, every element's inspection would point to the first line (being `/* typo */`). We deleted the file, created a new one and copied the contents and now it works. Never had this before....